# How to find the owner and who last update an object in Revit file with api c#

Tags: c#, api, revit

I am trying to make an application that can find out informaion a bout the objects in the model like the owner, last updated by, last updated date and so forth in worksharing file. I couldn't find any tutorial or example about that.
Does anybody know?
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Download the Revit SDK from http://usa.autodesk.com/adsk/servlet/index?siteID=123112&id=2484975.

Do a search for WorksharingUtils class.  There is a code sample that shows you what info is available.

Hope this helps.

```
public void GetElementWorksharingInfo(Document doc, Element elem)
{
    String message = String.Empty;
    message += "Element Id: " + elem.Id;

    // The workset the element belongs to
    WorksetId worksetId = elem.WorksetId;
    message += ("\nWorkset Id : " + worksetId.ToString());

    // Model Updates Status of the element
    ModelUpdatesStatus updateStatus = WorksharingUtils.GetModelUpdatesStatus(doc, elem.Id);
    message += ("\nUpdate status : " + updateStatus.ToString());

    // Checkout Status of the element
    CheckoutStatus checkoutStatus = WorksharingUtils.GetCheckoutStatus(doc, elem.Id);
    message += ("\nCheckout status : " + checkoutStatus.ToString());

    // Getting WorksharingTooltipInfo of a given element Id
    WorksharingTooltipInfo tooltipInfo = WorksharingUtils.GetWorksharingTooltipInfo(doc, elem.Id);
    message += ("\nCreator : " + tooltipInfo.Creator);
    message += ("\nCurrent Owner : " + tooltipInfo.Owner);
    message += ("\nLast Changed by : " + tooltipInfo.LastChangedBy);

    Autodesk.Revit.UI.TaskDialog.Show("GetElementWorksharingInfo", message);
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This is very helpful. I still looking for the date the element changed. Do you have an idea about that?

Comment: you would be able to log that information if you subscribe to a documentchanged event and log when certain elements are modified. You would then query that db to get your time info.  Since that event would be triggered frequently, I would be wary of model performance.  Take a look at the EventsMonitor project in the SDK Samples folder.